# Unable to click() div-element in embedded tableau

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, tableau-api

I'm having issues clicking the "Create PDF"-button in the embedded tableau frame on [this webpage](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_export_to_pdf.htm).

First, I call the element for the export button on the bottom of the tableau-iframe => works. That opens a Pop-Up window in the Tableau-Iframe. I then grab the Button-Container for both the Cancel and actual Download-Button. But no matter what I do, I'm not able to click the damn button.

Here's my code rn:

```
--grab export-button and click

var exportBtn = document.getElementById("btn-export-to-pdf");
exportBtn.click();

--grab "Create PDF" (or in German "PDF Erstellen") and click it

var buttn = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-pdf-dialog-buttons")[0].children.item(1)

buttn.click(); => returns undefined

var evnt = new Event("click");

buttn.dispatchEvent(evnt); => returns true
```

Any advice on how to click those kind of Buttons? It appears that tableau uses dojo, which coincides with some of these issue, but I wasn't able to figure anything more detailed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using javascript running in main page it is not possible to click the second button because it is located inside an `<iframe>` from a different domain. You can read more about Same-Origin-Policy on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

If you run this code inside a browser extension, selenium or similar please update your question as they might provide a way to do what you want.

Comment: Does that mean, that I could simply parse the iframe src, change the href of the current location and then proceed? Or am I on the wrong tracks here.

Comment: @drckeberger111 if you could provide more information on your overall setup and what you are trying to achieve it would help provide guidance on the solution

Comment: As you might have noticed, I'm a bloody beginner with js and all-around 'web-development'. 

My ultimate goal is to download tableau dashboards automatically, since I'm working with 20-30 different dashboards, that need to be inserted into a report. In my case per downloaded image.

Comment: In the case of automation you can use [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to access any information on the page and click even buttons within iframes.